# Limits of functions $f, g$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Find functions $f$ and $g$ such that these are satisfied.
$$\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = 2$$
$$\lim_{x \to 2} g(x) = 3$$
$$\lim_{x \to 1} g \circ f(x) = 4$$

I have tried many functions without success.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $f(x)=2$.

Define $g(x)$ by:$$  g(x) =
\begin{cases}
3,  & \text{if $x\neq 2$} \\
4, & \text{if $x=2$}
\end{cases}$$